# Where can I find experimental data supportive of the Hick-Hyman law?

Tags: data, psychophysics

The Hick-Hyman law states that in a reaction-time experiment, the average reaction time of a human subject is a linear function of the average information $\sum -p \log p$, i.e. the entropy, contained in the stimulus. [Hyman 1953]

Where can I get data supporting this? Data from Hyman’s paper would be great!

EDIT: more precisely, I'm looking for a complete, *trial-by-trial* dataset; not just averages.

Answer (score 1):

In [Hyman (1953)](http://www2.psychology.uiowa.edu/faculty/mordkoff/InfoProc/pdfs/Hyman%201953.pdf) the following data is shown (Fig.1). The bits of information were the number of choices in an AFC task, where 1 to 8 alternatives corresponded to 0, 1, 1.58, 2.00, 2.32, 2.58, 2.81, and 3 bits of information (the <sup>2</sup>log of the N alternatives).

[image: Hyman 1953]
<sup>Fig. 1. RT as a function of bits of info. source: [Hyman (1953)](http://www2.psychology.uiowa.edu/faculty/mordkoff/InfoProc/pdfs/Hyman%201953.pdf)</sup>

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Hyman, *J Exp Psychol* (1953); **45**(3): 188-96](http://www2.psychology.uiowa.edu/faculty/mordkoff/InfoProc/pdfs/Hyman%201953.pdf)</sub>

Comment: thanks, this is indeed the paper I'm referring to, in my question. I should have been much more precise in my question, so I've just edited it: I'm actually looking for trial-by-trial data, not averages.

Comment: Likely unavailable after more than 60 years.